# R: Renaming when using model.matrix

Tags: r, variable-names, model.matrix

When running the following R code:

```
y <- rnorm(100)  
B <- matrix(rnorm(200), ncol=2)  
colnames(B) <- c("x1", "x2")  
A <- model.matrix(y~B)  
colnames(A)
```

model.matrix adds to the variable names the prefix "B" in the matrix A. How can I avoid this behavior (or rename it but in a very general setting, e.g. within a function with user supplied formula)?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the "B" gets picked up from the object being used in `model.matrix`, so I suppose you can use that information to `gsub` it out if it's part of a function....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `sub` to remove the first character in the column names.

```
colnames(A)[-1] <- sub("^.", "", colnames(A)[-1])
```

Or set the column names by concatenating with the ones from 'B'

```
colnames(A) <- c(colnames(A)[1], colnames(B))
```

Another option without using the `sub` would be to create a data.frame with 'y' and 'B' matrix and then use `y ~.`

```
A <- model.matrix(y~., data=data.frame(y, B))
colnames(A)
#[1] "(Intercept)" "x1"          "x2"
```

Comment: If object "B" were named, instead, "akrun", the resulting column names would be "akrunx1" and "akrunx2". I think this could be made more extendable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replies.  It is planned to call it by A <- model.matrix(formula). If formula is defined as "y~B", then the problem arises, but not in other cases.